# single word to describe futuristic and modern building

Tags: single-word-requests

what would be a word to describe a building that is modern and futuristic.

a term that would mean something like '**building of the next decade/century**'

Answer (score 5):

Because architectural theorists/historians have defined modernism and futurism (and many derivations of these terms) to the past, I would be careful in using such terms. Two words that would generally avoid specific period definitions would be *contemporary* and *progressive*.

You could go with **[Post-Contemporary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-contemporary)** but that may be too esoteric.

Lastly — and this has nothing to do with your question — if the structure is made of the same stuff as the Sydney Opera House, please refer to it as concrete, not cement.

Comment: I've heard that 'contemporary' has also been assigned a specific meaning in the field of architecture, too.

Answer (score 4):

**[Neo-futurism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Futurism)** was coined as an early 21st century (that's now) movement that covers architecture, arts and design. I would suggest **neo-futuristic** is the appropriate adjective.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Neofuturistic was coined in the *early 60s*. The Sydney Opera House is a building of that style. It is *not* new to this century.

Comment: Pioneered in the early 60s and 70s, it is referred to as a *21st century movement*. The definition came from the reference made by Vito Di Bari, ... inspired by nanotechnology and the arts. The United States was pioneered in the 15th century, but it didn't become the United States until more than 200 years later.

Comment: @medica Neofuturism as a term was coined in the 1960s.  But, the movement has been relaunched in 2006.  All movements and art are derivative of the past.  Reusing the same name doesn't make the concept any less current.

Answer (score 2):

A futuristic and modern building might be called a **futurama**.

> [futurama](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/futurama): *(noun)* an exhibition or display that attempts to depict certain aspects or elements of life in the future.

---

> **[-rama](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=-rama&searchmode=none)** noun suffix meaning "**sight, view, spectacular display or instance of**," 1824, abstracted from panorama (q.v.), ultimately from Greek horama "sight, spectacle, that which is seen."

Comment: If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Answer (score 2):

I have always liked the expression '**cutting-edge architecture**'